# How to use for loop in JavaScript, especially in my program?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want to run the following program in a continuous loop till the length of my array. I want the program to run as it is for the first input then after first comparison the program should not end rather it should run till the for loop condition is satisfied. The program is as follows:

```
var userChoice = prompt("What would you like to select: rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

    if(computerChoice<0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    }
    else if(computerChoice<=0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    }
    else if(computerChoice<=1) {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    } 
    console.log("Computer: "+computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return "It is a tie!";
    }
    else if(choice1 === rock) {
        if(choice2 === paper) {
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else {
            return "rock wins";
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === paper) {
        if(choice2 === rock) {
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === scissors) {
        if(choice2 === paper) {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
        else {
            return "rock wins";
        }
    }
};
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

My array is: `var userChoice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];`

I tried it as:

```
var userChoice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
for(i=0; i<userChoice.length; i++) {
    var userChoice = prompt("What would you like to select: rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if(computerChoice<0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    }
    else if(computerChoice<=0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    }
    else if(computerChoice<=1) {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    } 
    console.log("Computer: "+computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return "It is a tie!";
    }
    else if(choice1 === rock) {
        if(choice2 === paper) {
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else {
            return "rock wins";
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === paper) {
        if(choice2 === rock) {
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === scissors) {
        if(choice2 === paper) {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
        else {
            return "rock wins";
        }
    }
};
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
}
```

but it gives me an error: `rock` is not defined.

Comment: hint - rock is not the same as "rock"

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? Are you confusing variables with string literals?

Comment: if you want to avoid all the quotes, you could do something like `rock = "rock"; paper = "paper"; scissors = "scissors"`

Comment: Another note.. using a `switch` would be more appropriate in my opinion.

Comment: Actually I am still learning JavaScript and I am only familiar till for loop. So I just can't use the switch statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed some quotes:-

```
var userChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
if(choice1 === choice2) {
   return "It is a tie!";
}
else if(choice1 === "rock") {
if(choice2 === "paper") {
    return "paper wins";
}
else {
    return "rock wins";
}
}
else if(choice1 === "paper") {
if(choice2 === "rock") {
    return "paper wins";
}
else {
    return "scissors wins";
}
}
else if(choice1 === "scissors") {
if(choice2 === "paper") {
    return "scissors wins";
}
else {
    return "rock wins";
}
}
};

for(i=0; i<userChoices.length; i++) {
var userChoice = prompt("What would you like to select: rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if(computerChoice<0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
}
else if(computerChoice<=0.67) {
computerChoice = "paper";
}
else if(computerChoice<=1) {
computerChoice = "scissors";
} 

var result = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
console.log("User: "+userChoice+", Computer: "+computerChoice+",  Result: "+result);
}
```

Comment: The output to your program comes as: 
Computer: paper 
Computer: rock 
Computer: scissors 
Computer: rock 
"It is a tie!"

Comment: Actually I want the output for each input but the program gives the output for the last input only.

Comment: I've modified my code, now you''be able to see the result in each iteration, but I still can't understand what is the user of the array when you're taking user input from prompt.